# Cannot sign in to the Github codespaces extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm facing problems when opening Codespace on the desktop version from VScode. I always get various problems and at any time. I was just using it from a day then I opened it today and tried to use Codespace but it's not responding and telling me I must sign in to ***Github Codespaces extension*** [Not sure how to make that!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgIyj.png), I opened the sittings for the extension but couldn't find anything related to it. Then I opened the developer tools and found two errors which says the same **sign in to ***Github Codespaces extension*****. What should I do ? I can't open it at all. The problem is also that it's not working only in the desktop version of VScode when I open it from the browser it's working, so I should be actually signed in to it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. Try to uninstall the extension and to reinstall it. It worked for me

Comment: Well, I tried doing so but it didn't work for me. Anyway it just fixed it self after some time...... thanks for trying!!